# How to run javascript functions sequentially from one click action?

Tags: javascript, scroll, reload, sequential

I want to use javascript to refresh my page and scroll to an anchor point (or scroll then refresh). I've tried doing it this way and then calling double('section') when a particular link is clicked in my website.

```
function double(place) {
  reload();
  jump(place);

}

function jump(h){
    var url = location.href;               //Save down the URL without hash.
    location.href = "#"+h;                 //Go to the target element.
    history.replaceState(null,null,url);
}

function reload(){
  onclick=window.location.reload(true); //Don't like hashes. Changing it back.
}
```

It isn't working though. If I remove reload() from within double(), then the jump() function works, but if I keep it as is below, the reload function runs but the jump does not seem to, or at least doesn't do what it is meant to.

Comment: Code execution cannot continue after page reload. But you can add code, that will be remove any hashes from URL on page load.

Comment: Ok, noted. What about something where once I click, the page scrolls down and then it reloads the page? That would work for me too but I can't seem to make both actions happen sequentially.

Comment: If you reload page after removing hash, you will be at start of page.